# How to get the Primary/Secondary color in jQuery UI Theme

Tags: css, jquery-ui, colors, themes

Is there a way to reference the colours used in the jQuery themes without creating a simple style for each theme that I may choose to use?

**Example**: I have some text as follows

`<div>Hello</div>`

which I'd like to be change colour in line with my theme of the day.  I wish to use the primary colour from a theme (say ui-lightness) which is "#1c94c4" as defined in several of the styles such as *ui-state-default* in *ui-lightness.css*

The problem is that if I do the following

`<div class='ui-state-default'>Hello</div>`

I get all the other style effects, like borders and background colour, which are not right for my application
What I'd like to do is something like

`<div class='ui-primary-color'>Hello</div>`

which would automatically change **only** the colour dependent on the theme.

PS. Doing a pre-build pre-processing step to parse the themes and generate a customised css style would be my least favourable option here!

Answer (score 1):

```
var color = $(".ui-state-default").css("color");
```

gave me color: "rgb(255, 255, 255)"

Comment: This will not work if the selected gets nothing for instance on page load ui-state-hover will have an empty selector.

Comment: Then simply wrap it in a if clause to check for a null/empty return set from the jQuery selector.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can can add any of the UI CSS directly to any html element, produce additional styles in separate classes to handle particular needs or even override a class to get rid of, say, a border style. Search for jQuery 'ThemeRoller-ready' sites.

I also suggest you to take a look at the [jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/).

[jQuery theming](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) page also worth reading.